# use of more (adv) with 'than

Tags: adverbs

We say:

I am more intelligent than you.

I earn more than you do.

I like you more than your brother.

Can we say:

You show devotion to me more than him.

I feel there has to be the preposition 'to' before 'him' and the adverb 'more' should be before the noun 'devotion'; as in

You show more devotion to me than to him.

Am I on right lines? If not, then is the following correct?

You show devotion to me more than him. [And what I mean to say by this sentence is: both 'me' and 'him' are the receivers of 'devotion' that 'You' show.]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

There is a subtle distinction between:

> You show more devotion to me than (to) him
>   and
>   You show devotion to me more than (to) him.

The first sentence refers to **more devotion** (a greater amount); the second implies more often. The use of the preposition **to** is optional. In colloquial speech it would often be omitted.

It's clear that **him** is the recipient of the devotion and not the giver.
Otherwise you would have to write:

> You show more devotion to me than he does.
>   or
>   You show devotion to me more than he does.